# Add a vertical scrollbar to WPF Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm kinda stuck on the ScrollViewer of my WPF Grid. I add elements to the Grid using code, so the Grid body in XAML is just empty. I also add ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions by code. This is the body of my Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="grdChampions" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="336" Margin="65,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="671">

</Grid>
```

Where do I have to add the ScrollViewer and what properties should it have?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You should embed the Grid Inside the ScrollViewer with the properties VerticalScrollBarVisibility and HorizontalScrollBarVisibility set to Auto

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid x:Name="grdChampions" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="336" Margin="65,60,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="671">
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Ahh I see, I forgot to update the height of the grid. That's why my ScrollViewer didn't show up. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to make the grid full size (eg. `VerticalAlignment="Stretch"`), but on the small screen, automatically display the vertical scroll bar when needed. Is it possible?

Comment: @sam It is possible to make appear and desappear the scroll bar depending on the size, as you mentioned when the screen is resized. I did using an event: SizeChanged="sizeChanged_ScrollViewer". In this event I get the actual height and then reduce the size of the grid: double parentHeight = NewFilesStack.ActualHeight;
            StatusGrid.Height = parentHeight - 40;

Comment: @VictorDavidFranciscoEnrique nice, thanks for posting the update. I actually don't use WPF for a long time. I hope your post can help some other person. +1 for the help. Thanks!