# ScrollViewer in WPF-Caliburn micro

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I can't make the **ScrollViewer** in **WPF** while using **Caliburn Micro MVVM** work! *https://github.com/moon1234moon/Factures*

Here is my **XML** code:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
              MaxHeight="900"
              MaxWidth="900"
              >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!-- Deleted because they are quite a lot -->

            <ContentControl Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5" 
                        x:Name="ActiveItem"
                        Margin="30, 150, 30, 30"
                        />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

Of-course I tried making the scroll enabled *IsEnabled = true* and added *VerticalAlignment* and *HorizentalAlignment* to it but non of that seemed to work!..

**Please Help!!**  **PS: The most important part is for me to be able to scroll horizontally to see the content of the ContentControl**

And here is the result:
[Image shows scroll to be not enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CyKX.png)

Comment: you dont want Scrollviewer inside Grid?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756920/add-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-wpf-grid this the correct way to do it.

Comment: is it usercontrol or window?

Comment: @Frenchy it is usercontrol

Comment: so i could help you but its difficult without more coding. could you post somewhere your solution (github or else)?

Comment: do you have twitter so I can text you?

Comment: I can send you an email too

Comment: I followed you I am @TravisN1213

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) put off the command MaxHeight and MaxWidth from your view which is usercontrol

2) put off the scrollviewer of the same view and define scrollviewer in the main window (shellview i suppose). The main window contents all usercontrols

3)all will be ok

Comment: I tried that too but the scrollbars will only disappear.